# convergence and sum of this series

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{n}-ln(1+\frac{1}{n}))$ is supposed to be convergent. If I use the integral test, I can prove the second term to be a finite integral while the first term is still divergent. So what is wrong with this approach, since I can see using a comparison test with 1/n^2 that it is convergent. How can I find the sum of this series ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) = \ln\frac{n+1}{n} = \ln(n+1)-\ln n$. You want $$\lim_{k\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^k \left(\frac{1}{n} - \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right);$$
apply the above simplification, see what happens to the series for finite $k$. Then look up the [formula for the Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Rewrite $$S_k=\sum_{n=1}^k \left(\frac{1}{n} - \log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)=\sum_{n=1}^k \left(\frac{1}{n} - \log(n+1) + \log(n)\right)$$ The first summation corresponds to $H_k$. For the second and third summations, you could see that they telescope. So, finally, you could arrive to $$S_k=H_k-\log (k+2)$$ For large values of $k$, use the asymptotic expansion of the harmonic number $$H_k=\gamma + \log(k)+\frac{1}{2 k}-\frac{1}{12
   k^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^4\right)$$ Similarly, $$\log(k+2)=\log(k) +\frac{2}{k}-\frac{2}{k^2}+\frac{8}{3
   k^3}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^4\right)$$ and finally, $$S_k=\gamma -\frac{3}{2 k}+\frac{23}{12 k^2}-\frac{8}{3
   k^3}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^4\right)$$